# Prettier for CSS - keeping spaces

Tags: css, prettier

When I save my css file, Prettier removes spaces, but
I want to keep spaces between css selectors and modifiers.
So, I want this:

```
.some > span {...
```

instead of this:

```
.some>span {...
```

How can I override these settings in my .prettier.js ?

```
module.exports = {
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": "*.scss",
      "options": {
          "keepSpaces": true <-- not existing rule :)
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

Comment: Having the same issue as you 5 years later. Have you been able to solve this OP?

Answer (score 0):

On vscode:
Ctrl + Shift + P

> Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)

```
"[css]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
```

Save and try

Comment: While this doesn't seem to be the right answer, funnily this was what fixed my issue. I had configured prettier as the formatter for js, ts, etc., but css was still handled by vscode's default css formatter. Anybody else with this issue, please make sure to check it is prettier that is removing your spaces.