# How to avoid removing white spaces in CSS files in VS Code?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, prettier

Having CSS file where the structure is like this:

```
#something > div {
...
}
```

When it is saved, it removes the spaces around the child combinator (`>`) and it makes it look like this:

```
#something>div {
...
}
```

Is there a way to avoid this in VS Code?

Comment: It doesn't by default so if you didn't set it yourself, it might be from an extension you're using

Answer (score 6):

I haven't encountered this in VS Code. But I did find this setting in Preferences>Settings that may be the solution.

[image]

I do not have it checked and I don't have the same issue you report. Perhaps another setting elsewhere causes it.

Answer (score 0):

For those that don't like [images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541), the setting being referenced in [CChoma's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74877715/11107541) is `css.format.spaceAroundSelectorSeparator`, which has a default value of `false`. The setting's description is:

> Ensure a space character around selector separators '>', '+', '~' (e.g. `a > b`).

If you're using a non-default CSS formatter such as Prettier, consult the configuration documentation for your formatter. I tried reproducing this behaviour with the Prettier extension but could not, and didn't see any settings related to spaces or CSS combinators in the VS Code Prettier settings, or [the Prettier options docs](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html). Interestingly, there is a similar question here: [Prettier for CSS - keeping spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51632787/11107541). I tried googling for info related to this with various search queries like `github prettier issues space CSS child`, `github prettier issues space CSS combinator`, etc. but didn't see anything that looked related.

Answer (score -2):

Replace space -

```
--space--- > --space--- replace to  = >
```

[image]

Comment: This answer fixes the problem after it occurs. The OP wants to prevent it from occurring in the first place.